# Reading Audio Data from MP3 using Naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to **split the audio data** of a mp3 file and perform an **FFT transformation** on each of the chunks.

All of my attempts to read from the audio stream did not work so far. 
Here is the code for my last attempt (it uses a wav file)

```
        using (var ms = File.OpenRead("reggae.wav"))
         using (var rdr = new WaveFileReader(ms)) 
         {
             int steps = 100;
             int stepSize = (int)rdr.Length / steps;

             byte[][] audData = new byte[steps][];


             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                 audData[i] = new byte[stepSize];
                 rdr.Read(audData[i], i * steps, stepSize);
             }

         }
```

I get an array out of bounds exception with this code.

What kind of streams do I have to use and how do I read the data from it?

Is there any **documentation for the naudio api**?

Answer (score 3):

the array out of bounds exception is caused by you passing in a non-zero value for offset to the Read method. It should be:

```
rdr.Read(audData[i], 0, stepSize);
```

There are several articles on the web explaining how to do different things in NAudio

- [NAudio articles on my blog](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/search/label/NAudio)
- [Skype Voice Changer article at Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2009/02/02/9391048.aspx)
- [.NET Voice Recorder article at Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx)

For examples of using FFT with NAudio, look at the WpfDemo app in the NAudio source code, and also at the .NET voice recorder application [source code](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com) (hopefully another article on Coding4Fun will appear shortly).

Comment: Yeah, you are right with the offset. How would you read a complete wave file into memory?

Comment: Jochen - Read it in to a MemoryStream