# Analyze Audio Spectrum without playing it

Tags: c#, audio

I am currently trying to analyze an audio spectrum of an audio file (mp3) in C#. For example, I have a 3-minute track that should return 512 frequency values 60 times per second.

I want to save all of these values in a 2D Array `[timestamp][value at frequency]`. I want to do this in not-realtime because the values are needed later for rendering an audio visualizer. The real-time solution wouldn't be able to handle all these complex scenes at once.

Comment: what is the format of your file?

Comment: it's a mp3 file

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463260/reading-audio-data-from-mp3-using-naudio it might have some bits of information that will help you.

Comment: This question might have already been asked before. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245450/how-to-create-audio-spectrum-in-c-sharp

Comment: Actually he has not asked a question yet.